# AWS CDK Credentials not found when Bootstrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, zsh, aws-cdk

I'm getting the following error within zsh when issuing the command:

Command -     `~ % cdk bootstrap aws://******/*region*`

Error (snip) - `Environment aws://******/*region* failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account ******, but no credentials have been configured`

When I run aws configure, I'm able to set my temporary credentials and verify they are written to the Credentials file within users/username/.aws

When I try to run the same commands from an ec2 linux instance, everything works fine. How can I get the cdk to properly locate my credentials file on my local machine?

Comment: Fully close & reload your zsh shell after setting your credentials

Comment: -Ran aws configure
-Fully Closed Terminal
-Ran bootstrap command

Same issue.

Comment: Whats the contents of the credential file look like, maybe you need to pass `--profile <profile_name>` and use one of the profiles you have configured, but isn't the default profile?

Comment: [default]
aws_access_key_id = *******
aws_secret_access_key = *******

If the credentials file had wrong creds or was formatted incorrectly, wouldn't an error be thrown stating so? I wouldn't think a 'file not found' error would occur if incorrect creds were the case.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by adding AWS_SESSION_TOKEN to my .aws/credentials file. It would be helpful if you could specify your Session Token right from the `aws configure` command.